# Using the javascript spread operator to pass unknown number of variables to a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, spread-syntax

I've created a small library (module) to re-route commands in Node/Javascript, and rather than repetitively spell out what every var could be in each function, I'm passing them along in bulk:

```js
const library = require('path');

export function myFunction(...args){
  return library.myFunction(...args);
}
```

My question is: am I doing it wrong? Or is this doing what I think it is: taking an unknown number of inputs, and passing them along to a function...

Comment: You're doing it right.

Comment: It seems right to me!

Comment: In cases where you don't change anything, you could also map the function directly: `export const myFunction = library.myFunction.bind(library)`

Comment: This is when you test.